# SSH into a Docker Container and list the files and directories

Tags: ssh, azure, docker, azure-app-services

[image]

We have an SSH connection to our Docker container in an Azure App Service. How do we access the file system? We have tried dir and ls. There appear to be no files or directories in the container, even though the container is actively running a live Django site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate what you did in the Bash console and I got similar results. With no D directory being available.  [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvrYP.png)

But I was able to do:

```
cd /
```

and

```
cd ../
```

And see and access parent folders.  [More Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTnr0.png)

Also, here's the link for the bashshell in kudu if needed:
***https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/Default.cshtml***

Comment: I needed `cd ..` It simply didn't occur to me to try. Lol.

Comment: : Happens all the time with new ventures, so much new stuff that sometimes the simplest things slip our minds.  Cool that you're exploring containers on Azure.